# Blazer component - Localization not working on language change

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I created the resource file for localization. while page loading, it sets the current culture info but changing the language from drop down list, it's not changing.

Here is my code,

**MainLayout.razor:**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="sidebar">
  <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
   <div class="top-row px-4">
      <select @onchange="OnSelected">
         <option value="en">English</option>
         <option value="de">German</option>
      </select>
   </div>
  <div class="content px-4">
     @Body
  </div>
</div>

@code {
   private void OnSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
   {
      var selectedCulture = e.Value.ToString();
      CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = 
         CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
            .First(c => c.Name == selectedCulture);
   }
}
```

**Localization.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inject IStringLocalizer<Localization> localizer

<h3>@localizer["Title"]</h3>
@localizer["Content"]
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        
        services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("de") };
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("de");
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
        app.UseRouting();

        app.ApplicationServices
            .UseBootstrapProviders()
            .UseFontAwesomeIcons();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

**Resx:**

Localization.resx:

[image]

Localization.de.resx:

[image]

While changing the language in MainLayout.razor page, it's not changing the text in Localization.razor page based on language selection. What I need to do for changing text in all pages?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526006/globalization-and-localization-in-blazor-server-app