# Globalization and Localization in Blazor Server App

Tags: localization, blazor, blazor-server-side

How to do globalization and localization in Blazor Server App ?

Not being able to find a working sample of globalization and localization in Blazor Server App,
I've created one of my own. Here's the code sample. Copy and test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a folder and name it Resources
2. Add the following resource files (`.resx`) to the folder
   `Pages.Index.resx`: Add the string Greetings to the Name column and Hello! to
   the Value column

   `Pages.Index.fr.resx`: Add the string Greetings to the Name column and Bonjour!
   to the Value column

   `Pages.Index.de.resx`: Add the string Greetings to the Name column and Hallo
   to the Value column
3. Add a component named CultureSelector.razor to the Shared folder:

### CultureSelector.razor

```
@using  System.Globalization
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@using System.Threading

<div>@SelectedCulture</div>

<select value="@SelectedCulture" @onchange="OnSelected">
    @foreach (var culture in Cultures)
    {
        <option value="@culture.Value">@culture.Caption</option>
    }
</select>


@code {

    private void OnSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var culture = (string)e.Value;
        var uri = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri)
            .GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        var query = $"?culture={Uri.EscapeDataString(culture)}&" +
            $"redirectUri={Uri.EscapeDataString(uri)}";

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Culture/SetCulture" + query, forceLoad: true);
    }

    public string SelectedCulture { get; set; } = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;

    public class CultureData
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public List<CultureData> Cultures { get; set; } = new List<CultureData>()
    {
        new  CultureData() { Caption = "English", Value = "en-US" },
        new  CultureData() { Caption = "French", Value = "fr-FR" },
        new  CultureData() { Caption = "German", Value = "de-DE" },
    };
}
```

Instantiate the CultureSelector component in MainLayout like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Reflection
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <CultureSelector></CultureSelector>
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

### Usage (Index.razor)

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<Index> localizer

<h1>@localizer["Greetings"].Value</h1>



@code{ }
```

### Startrup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = 
                                                      "Resources");
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddControllers();
       
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            // define the list of cultures your app will support
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
                                    {
                                         new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                         new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                                         new CultureInfo("de-DE")
                                    };

            // set the default culture
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");

            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

      app.UseRequestLocalization(
     app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>> 
                                                                    ().Value);
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            // enable controllers for the culture controller
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Add a Controller class to the Controllers folder (if exists. If not add one)
Name it CultureController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace <Put here the namespace of your app>.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class CultureController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string redirectUri)
        {
            if (culture != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
                        new RequestCulture(culture)));
            }

            return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
        }
        public IActionResult ResetCulture(string redirectUri)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName);

            return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution and it works, I have a question though, what if you want to create a resource file which have common resources that you would use in multiple pages/components, text like, Save, Error, Delete, Update
I want to add these kind of texts in a resource and use it instead of copying them everywhere

Answer (score 0):

After a long search for SEO-friendly culture links in Blazor, I finally discovered the solution I was looking for: [www.side.com/en-US/index](http://www.side.com/en-US/index). This comprehensive tutorial made the difference:
https://ghostlyinc.com/en-US/seo-friendly-culture-links-in-blazor/
It works well!